# Issue while configuration of CAS with Jasper Server 4.7.0

Tags: single-sign-on, cas, jasperserver

I'm facing an issue while configuration of CAS with Jasper Server 4.7.0. I have read the Authentication Cookbook 4.0 and the following url :-

[CAS Integration](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/integrating-cas-jasperreports-server)

Please find the stacktrace of the same below:-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.service.impl.hibernate.HibernateRepositoryServiceImpl.getResourcesCount(HibernateRepositoryServiceImpl.java:2192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy13.getResourcesCount(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.service.EasyXMLizer.invoke(EasyXMLizer.java:44)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.PermissionsPrefetcher.invoke(PermissionsPrefetcher.java:78)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.user.service.impl.PermissionsPrefetcher.invoke(PermissionsPrefetcher.java:78)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.security.intercept.method.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy17.getResourcesCount(Unknown Source)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.multipleTenancy.PathTransformationRepositoryService.getResourcesCount(PathTransformationRepositoryService.java:599)
    at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.export.impl.AdhocUpgradeExecutorImpl.upgrade(AdhocUpgradeExecutorImpl.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy60.upgrade(Unknown Source)
    at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.export.listeners.AdhocUpgradeListener.onApplicationEvent(AdhocUpgradeListener.java:25)
    at com.jaspersoft.ji.adhoc.export.listeners.AdhocUpgradeListener.onApplicationEvent(AdhocUpgradeListener.java:15)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:97)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:324)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:929)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4350)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4816)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:810)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:788)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1051)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectories(HostConfig.java:977)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:507)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1322)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1036)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:773)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1028)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:278)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:429)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:662)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:592)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:290)
```

Please help in this.

Thanks in Advance.